# Use javascript to hide 'player-api' from youtube

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm trying to use javascript to show/hide the 'player-api' div tag on a YouTube video URL. The idea is that I load a button through a chrome extension that the user can then click.

I'm receiving an error saying "3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" on line 11 (the line of code where it starts messing with the display after getting the ID of player-api).

I'm assuming that the issue will have something to do with the extension not actually being able to see player-api to affect it. I have no idea how to fix that though and similar questions haven't really helped me out.

Could anyone tell me for sure what I'm doing wrong and how I would fix it?

**Javascript**

```
var button = document.createElement("Button");
var t = document.createTextNode("Show/Hide");
button.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener('click', toggleVisibility, false);


function toggleVisibility() {
    var e = document.getElementById('player-api');
    if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Player-API's Popup</title>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
  </head>

  <body>

  <script src="popup.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "player-api",
    "description": "This extension will show/hide Youtube videos",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeContent",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "*://*.youtube.com/*" ],
            "js": [ "popup.js" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please post your html to can check it too

Comment: Could you post more relevant source code please *html* And you have another problem with this method. I have used youtubes API and found some browsers would remove the video ID from the player or stop the video when using display:none; but this all depends if you use the API to set the player ID  or use javascript to set the src of an iframe.

Comment: Sorry I'll add it now. There's really nothing to it though which is why it wasn't there in the first place. I think I call the .js file in the body of the extension but that's it. @NewToJS I'm specifically targeting chrome so as long as player-api exists in that browser I'm happy haha. I'm aware of iframe being used in IE though :)

Comment: How is player-API element loaded?

Comment: So essentially I want the button that is clicked to affect code on the webpage rather than in the extension itself. I think that's the problem I just don't know how to do it haha. @PhilipG I think that's the part I need to figure out haha. It exists on the actual YouTube webpage so I need a way for the extension to identify it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be added at all right now. And your discribed problem also implies that. So again where/when is that element added? You can't show/hide elements that doesn't exist

Comment: I haven't got a method to add it in my code. I think the main issue is I don't know how. How would I add the element to the extension? It exists in the source code of a YouTube video URL, at least on Google Chrome anyway. Is there a way for the button to see that element and manipulate it?

Comment: Can i get any other help with this? Recently discovered that when I run the document with: "run_at": "document_end" then the div will hide but obviously I can't get it back. But why one way and not the other?